# Cannot push to github with the unreal engine

Tags: git, github, unreal-engine4, git-lfs

So I followed this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5Yn7y9Ib_I&

And got this error message.

> Enumerating objects: 2360, done. Counting objects: 100% (2360/2360),
> done. Delta compression using up to 6 threads Compressing objects:
> 100% (2355/2355), done. error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure:
> Connection was aborted send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading
> sideband packet Writing objects: 100% (2360/2360), 2.59 GiB | 14.22
> MiB/s, done. Total 2360 (delta 61), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly Everything up-to-date

I did everything in that tutorial except when I first tried to push it said that large files  could not be uploaded. I did install GitLFS. Im wondering if GitLFS was not installed correctly and if I need to do it again.

Is there a way I can make sure that GitLFS is installed correctly?

Comment: This appears to be normal behavior.  The fatal error is that there are no changes that require uploading.

Comment: It doesn't upload any files. It doesn't create the project in my GitHub Account

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be an error due to Git LFS [If you have correctly specified the git attributes]. Have you tried pulling the repo/branch to a new folder again, and then copy your unreal project over there and push it. I guess something should be stopping you from copying files to repo because you haven't pulled the recent version [something even small like read me].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried uploading a random project and it worked. I have figured out that it does have something to do with large files and GIT LFS. Is there a way that I can figure out if GIT LFS has been installed correctly?